# Faster Whisper float 16 issue

Tags: python, cuda, cudnn, openai-whisper

I wanted to use faster whisper so i used the example they provided such as

```
def transcribe(audio):
    model = WhisperModel("small")
    segments, info = model.transcribe(audio)
    language = info[0]
    print("Transcription language", info[0])
    segments = list(segments)

    for segment in segments:
        print("[%.2fs -> %.2fs] %s" % (segment.start, segment.end, segment.text))
    return language, segments
```

and run into this issue:
Error : [ctranslate2] [thread 28968] [warning] The compute type inferred from the saved model is float16, but the target device or backend do not support efficient float16 computation. The model weights have been automatically converted to use the float32 compute type instead.

I installed cuda 11.8 and cudnn 9 (Cuda is in system path(nvcc --version work). ) but still error.
I am using conda env but never got problem with path and venv.
Any idea ?

### **EDIT: Found the error thanks to Abator Abetor and Jérôme Richard. GPU doesn't have Tensor cores**

Comment: Does your gpu support efficient float16 computation?

Comment: I think ? how do i check this ?

Comment: you need a gpu with at least tensor cores. this is not really a cuda question.

Comment: https://github.com/SYSTRAN/faster-whisper/issues/42

Comment: To be honest, the error is misleading (if not simply wrong). It is all about tensorcore indeed and not FP16 alone. I was confused myself when I tested on a GPU capable of doing FP16 operations faster than FP32. I am not totally convinced about their argument: "currently we disable FP16 without Tensor Cores as it has worse performance than FP32 in my experience".

Comment: In fact, I think the GPU implementation is not optimized as it could be as CPUs achieve relatively good performance compared to GPUs without tensorcores and one with tensorcore a not massively faster too. A 16 core CPU using FP32 turns out to be quite competitive with a GPU not supporting TCs nor FP16 (having the same TDP) which is at best surprising.